# accessing the taglib in service

Tags: grails, namespaces, taglib

I have a custom taglib with namespace xyz.  I want to access the methods of this taglib in a service. If I import it and use xyz.someFunction(). It does not recognize it. How do we access the namespace of a taglib from outside?

Comment: This link shows you, I believe. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159423/how-to-call-a-taglib-as-a-function-in-a-domain-class

Answer (score 5):

if you want to use your custom taglib in service class, use the code below.

```
def c = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('com.custom.MyCustomTagLib');
int age = c.calculateAge(dob);
```

More details can be found [here](http://www.ygrails.com/2012/10/30/access-taglib-in-service-class/)

Answer (score -1):

Taglibs contain logic related to view whereas services contain business logic. I dont see any reason for using taglibs in services. If you are doing so, it's probably a design mistake. Can you please give a reason of why you want to use taglib in services?

Comment: I was using the service which send emails. And in order to follow the DRY principle I wished to use already written code.

Comment: I would suggest to move that common logic in some service or utility class instead of having it in taglib.