# Cannot use grails g.link in domain class

Tags: grails

I have static method in a domain class that returns a url.  I need to build that url dynamically but g.link isn't working.

```
static Map options() {
    // ...
    def url = g.link( controller: "Foo", action: "bar" )
    // ...
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
Apparent variable 'g' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'g' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
 @ line 17, column 19.
           def url = g.link( controller: "Foo", action: "bar" )
                     ^

1 error
```

Obviously my problem is that I am trying to access `g` from static context, so how do I get around this?

Comment: Don't do this in a static scope.  Use an instance method, or even better, put this code in a service so it can be injected.

Comment: I don't have an instance at the time I am doing this.

Comment: Yea, I agree with OverZealous.  Really bad idea to do it this way.

Comment: @typoknig: Then you are doing something very, *very* wrong.  Controllers should never be used for generic code.

Comment: The reason I am doing this is because I am building a flexigrid.  The flexigrid will contain many objects of a specific type, so it makes sense to me that the method be static.  The url is part of the options needed by the flexigrid.

Comment: @OverZealous this isn't in a controller, it is in a domain class (see question title) :)

Comment: Doh! typo.  Fixing question title.  Almost comical when you consider my user name :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `g` object is a taglib, which is not available inside a domain class like it would be in a controller.  You can get at it through the `grailsApplication` as shown here: [How To Call A Taglib As A Function In A Domain Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159423/how-to-call-a-taglib-as-a-function-in-a-domain-class)

A better way to do this in Grails 2+ is through the `grailsLinkGenerator` service, like so:

```
def grailsLinkGenerator

def someMethod() {
    def url = grailsLinkGenerator.link(controller: 'foo', action: 'bar')
}
```

In both cases, you'll need to do some extra work to get `grailsApplication`/`grailsLinkGenerator` from a static context.  The best way is probably to grab it off the `domainClass` property of your domain class:

```
def grailsApplication = new MyDomain().domainClass.grailsApplication
def grailsLinkGenerator = new MyDomain().domainClass.grailsApplication.mainContext.grailsLinkGenerator
```

Comment: I was so close.  I did try linkGenerator, but I was getting static context warnings.  Grabbing it off the domain class as you suggested worked good.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Grails 2.x you can use the LinkGenerator API.  Here's an example, I am re-using a domain class I was testing with earlier so ignore the non-url related functionality.

```
class Parent {
    String pName

    static hasMany = [children:Child]

    static constraints = {
    }
    static transients = ['grailsLinkGenerator']

    static Map options() {
        def linkGen = ContextUtil.getLinkGenerator();
        return ['url':linkGen.link(controller: 'test', action: 'index')]
    }
}
```

**Utility Class with Static Method**

```
@Singleton
class ContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext context

    void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {
        this.context = context
    }

    static LinkGenerator getLinkGenerator() {
        getInstance().context.getBean("grailsLinkGenerator")
    }

}
```

**Bean Def for New Utility Bean**

```
beans = {
    contextUtil(ContextUtil) { bean ->
        bean.factoryMethod = 'getInstance'
    }
}
```

If you need the base URL, add `absolute:true` to the link call.